# assert() leads to maybe-uninitialized gcc warning

Tags: c++, gcc, assert, eigen3

The following code compiles fine, with no warnings/errors:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using Array = Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1>;

struct Tree {
  Array array;
  std::bitset<8> bitset;
};

auto func(Tree* tree) {
  int c = tree->array.rows();
  int d = tree->bitset.count();
  //assert(c==d);
  Array e(c);
  for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) e(k) = k;
  return e.sum() / (e + 1);
}

int main() {
  Tree tree;
  func(&tree);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation cmd:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -I anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/ test.cpp
```

However, when I uncomment the `assert()`, I get a maybe-uninitialized warning:

```
In file included from anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:253,
                 from test.cpp:2:
In member function ‘Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<LhsScalar, RhsScalar>::result_type Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<LhsScalar, RhsScalar>::operator()(const LhsScalar&, const RhsScalar&) const [with LhsScalar = float; RhsScalar = float]’,
    inlined from ‘static Eigen::internal::redux_impl<Func, Evaluator, 3, 0>::Scalar Eigen::internal::redux_impl<Func, Evaluator, 3, 0>::run(const Evaluator&, const Func&, const XprType&) [with XprType = Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1>; Func = Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float, float>; Evaluator = Eigen::internal::redux_evaluator<Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1> >]’ at anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:278:19,
    inlined from ‘typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::redux(const Func&) const [with BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float, float>; Derived = Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1>]’ at anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:418:56,
    inlined from ‘typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::sum() const [with Derived = Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1>]’ at anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:463:25,
    inlined from ‘auto func(Tree*)’ at test.cpp:17:15:
anaconda3/envs/dev/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/functors/BinaryFunctors.h:42:122: warning: ‘((const float*)((char*)&e + offsetof(Eigen::Array, Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1>::<unnamed>.Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1, 0, 3, 1> >::m_storage)))[3]’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   42 |   EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE result_type operator() (const LhsScalar& a, const RhsScalar& b) const { return a + b; }
      |                                                                                                                        ~~^~~
test.cpp: In function ‘auto func(Tree*)’:
test.cpp:15:9: note: ‘e’ declared here
   15 |   Array e(c);
      |         ^
```

My question is this: **why does the presence of the `assert()` affect whether or not gcc reports a maybe-uninitialized warning**?

The example I show happens to use the eigen3 library, but I think my question is more general. How can the inclusion of an `assert()` that merely compares two int values lead to a compiler warning like this?

I want to note that this code is a minimal reproducible example for this assert-dependent-warning behavior. Removing the for-loop inside `func()`, for instance, makes the warning appear even without the assert. Replacing `e.sum() / (e + 1)` with a simpler expression like `e + 1` makes the warning disappear with the assert. Replacing the `std::bitset` with something else also makes the warning disappear with the assert.

I am using gcc-11.3.0 and eigen-3.4.0.

Comment: It looks like a false positive. Probably because `assert` could lead to `abort` being called, which doesn't return. And then `e` will indeed by uninitialized, but on the other hand that code wouldn't even run which is what makes the message false.

Comment: On a different note, please don't use `assert` for run-time checks. First in "release" builds (with the macro `NDEBUG` defined) it will do nothing. And otherwise if the assert fails then it will "crash" the program which isn't very helpful for the users of your program.

Comment: If I replace `//assert(c==d)` with `assert(false)` or `assert(c==2*d)`, I do not get the warning. Is this consistent with your hypothesis?

Comment: This seems to be related to the optimization. If I build with `-O1` [I don't get any warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/8dE6d3sxj). `-O2` and `-O3` gives warnings. Also, I don't get the warning if I build with the address or UB sanitizers (`-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`), even with `-O3`. This kind of compiler-behavior makes me think "bug".

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oq1qEdTW5) is a demonstration of how the behavior disappears with seemingly unrelated changes. Might this be a gcc bug?

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug. I recommend you go to their [bugtracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and report it.

Comment: [Reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108230). Will add an answer here based on responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently due to a gcc bug. The bug is present in gcc-12 or lower, and is fixed in gcc-13. A fix might be coming in gcc-12.

Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108230